# Construct portfolio given certain payoff function

Tags: finance, economics, actuarial-science

My question is similar to https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37419/replicate-a-portfolio-with-given-payoff but I am not quite sure how to apply this to my problem.

A portfolio of European call options on an asset $S$ has a payoff function given by $V_T$ where
$$V_T = 0,\ S < A$$
$$V_T = S - A , \ A \leq S \leq B$$
$$V_T = B - A, \ S > B$$

> (i) Construct a portfolio $H_1$ of European call options with this payoff function.
>
> (ii) Use Put-Call parity to construct a portfolio $H_2$ of European put
> options with this payoff function.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a **call spread**. Buy one call at strike $A$ and sell one call at strike $B$ for part (i). Once you know (i), you should be able to get (ii). Also see the sections at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bull_spread).

Comment: "A bull put spread is constructed by selling higher striking in-the-money put options and buying the same number of lower striking out-of-the-money put options" so would I not do the same thing except with put options? Sell one put at strike B and buy 1 put at strike A?

Answer (score 0):

A long European call with strike A has the payoff: $C(T)=(S(T)-A)^+$ such that, if it goes 'in the money', the profit is of $S-A$. 
A short European call with strike B has the payoff: $C(T)=-(S(T)-B)^=(S(T)-B)^-+$  such that if it goes in the money, its payoff is of $B-S$. 
Now, if you construct a portfolio made of this short and long call, given that $A<B$, at time T:

if $S<A$, we end up 'out of the money' so our profit is 0;

if $A\leq S \leq B$ (here, it would be better to leave out that equal sign to A), only the long call is 'in the money' so our profit is $S-A$

if $S > B$, both are 'in the money', so the profit we end up with is given by: $S-A-(S-B)=B-A$

This option strategy gives you the same payoff as the initial function as you can see.

Now, apply the Put-Call Parity noting that:

$P(T)=C(T)-S(T)+K$

Therefore, the long call becomes: $P(T)=(S(T)-A)^+ -S(T)+A=(A-S(T))^+$, i.e. a long put; the short call becomes: $P(T)=-(S(T)-B)^++B-S(T)=-(B-S(T))^+$, i.e. a short put. This comes as no surprise because their payoff diagrams are mirror images. 
So, noting that $A<B$, you will have replicated the portfolio with puts.

Hope this helps!